# How to get week number from date input in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, week-number

I am trying to get the week number of current date / specific date falls in. Any suggestions for logic building will be helpful.

Comment: Have a look on that maybe : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045868/javascript-date-getweek

Comment: May check out [moment](http://momentjs.com/) if you want to work with dates in JS.

Comment: Do you want to get an ISO standard week number, or some localized week number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getWeekNumber(thisDate) {
var dt = new Date(thisDate);
var thisDay = dt.getDate();

var newDate = dt;
newDate.setDate(1); // first day of month
var digit = newDate.getDay();

var Q = (thisDay + digit) / 7;

var R = (thisDay + digit) % 7;

if (R !== 0) return Math.ceil(Q);
else return Q;}
```

getWeekNumber("07/31/2016");

Comment: You should not parse strings using the Date constructor (or Date.parse, they are equivalent for parsing). It does not make sense to use Date methods to create a string to then parse to another Date (e.g. to get the first of the month), just use Date methods directly: `newDate.setDate(1)`.

Answer (score -7):

```
let _ = new Date,
    __ = ~~((new Date(_.getFullYear(), 0, 0) - _) / 36e5 * 24),
    ___ = (__ - __ % 7) / 7;
```

Comment: Care for additional explanation (like why you're using underscores instead of names)?